# Why are some html tags invisible when scraping?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm trying to scrape text from [here](https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/R3_F1/scene/3.6/index.html) to input directly into an excel sheet, rather than copy and pasting. The website uses Html to include information about the original typeface. This is an example for how one line of text is coded on the page:

```
<div class="line">
    <span class="milestone_wrap"> </span>
    <a id="tln-2212" href="index.html#tln-2212" class="milestone tln invisible" title="TLN: 2212">2212</a>
    <span class="milestone_wrap">When </span>
    <span class="typeform" data-setting="ſ">s</span>
    <span class="milestone_wrap">uch ill dealing mu</span>
    <span class="ligature" data-precomposed="ﬅ">
        <span class="typeform" data-setting="ſ">s</span>
        <span class="milestone_wrap">t</span>
    </span>
    <span class="milestone_wrap"> be </span>
    <span class="typeform" data-setting="ſ">s</span>
    <span class="milestone_wrap">eene in thought. </span>
    <span class="sd exit">
        <span class="space" style="padding-right:1em;" xml:space="preserve"></span>
        <i>Exit</i>
        <span class="milestone_wrap">.</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have tried using the find_all method

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/R3_F1/scene/3.6/index.html'
page = requests.get(url)
text = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')

divs = text.find_all('div', class_="line")
for div in divs:
    for item in div.contents: print(item)
```

This is what I get back:

```
When 
<span class="typeform" data-setting="ſ">s</span>
uch ill dealing mu
<span class="ligature" data-precomposed="ﬅ"><span class="typeform" data-setting="ſ">s</span>t</span>
 be 
<span class="typeform" data-setting="ſ">s</span>
eene in thought. 
<span class="sd exit"><span class="space" style="padding-right:1em;" xml:space="preserve"> </span><i>Exit</i>.</span>
```

Everything with the tag `<span class="milestone_wrap">` appears without the tag: therefore, when I use .find_all for 'span', these strings then don't come up and so I'm left with random letters. Is there a reason why that class isn't appearing?

Answer (score 1):

Work at the level of `line` class but decompose the `a` tags, so as to remove the line numbers; unless you really want them, in which case, I would add space between them and the following text:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/R3_F1/scene/3.6/index.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for line in soup.select('.line'):
    line.select_one('a').decompose()
    print(line.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

When executing your code with a little adjustment (the **requests** module must be imported) you should get the content of the site.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/R3_F1/scene/3.6/index.html'
page = requests.get(url)
text = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')

divs = text.find_all('div', class_="line")
for div in divs:
    for item in div.contents: print(item)
```

The text can be found within the `<span class="milestone_wrap">` tags. You can check this with the *inspector* of your browser. The text is delivered in small portions tag by tag, e.g. "Which in a". You should be able to extract the text.

Comment: I forgot to paste in the first line of code, but I did import requests - the tag for that class is still not showing up